# How to comment out a 'php' line in an php document

Tags: php

The following is my `index.php` file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Super Express Logistics Services</title>
<?php include 'php/includes.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>
<?php include 'php/page01.php'?>
<?php include 'php/page02.php'?>
<?php include 'php/page03.php'?>
<?php include 'php/page04.php'?>
</body>

</html>
```

It's actually a pain to scroll down page01 through page03 to check the development of page04, again and again.

```
/*<?php include 'page1.php'?>*/
```

Turns out, the `<?php...?>` is still compiled and is not skipped as comment.
How do I comment out any `<?php...??` lines like these ?

Comment: `<?php  /* include 'php/includes.php';  */  ?>`

Comment: You've got to add the comment inside of the `<?php` tag. Including it before the tag is not valid HTML for one thing, more importantly php still processes the include directive.

Comment: Okay, I think, I get it now! Answers did help. But what do you mean by `php still processes the include directive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using PHP comment syntax outside of PHP which won't do anything and still load the PHP (Note that HTML style comments are `<!-- -->`). You want to use [PHP comments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php) *within* your PHP which will prevent the PHP from executing.

```
<?php /* include 'php/page04.php' */ ?>
```

or

```
<?php // include 'php/page04.php'?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `<?php // include 'php/page01.php'?>`

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to comment multiple PHP lines together then you can use multi line comments that begins with `/*` and ends with `*/` like below:

```
<?php 
/* include 'php/page01.php'; 
   include 'php/page02.php';
   include 'php/page03.php';
   include 'php/page04.php'; */
?>
```

And If you want to comment single line only then you can use `//` or `#` like below:

```
<?php // include 'php/page04.php'; ?>
```

Or

```
<?php # include 'php/page04.php'; ?>
```

In your case, you are trying PHP comments outside PHP syntax that is not possible so you have to comment inside PHP syntax only.

Learn more about PHP comments at http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

Answer (score 0):

You should do this `<?php /*include 'page1.php'*/ ?>` instead because:

PHP `<?php ?>` is processed on the server and the output is returned as HTML in this case "thats why its called Hyper text pre-processor"

Once the php opening tag `<?php` is seen  you are in PHP environment and whatever is between this tag and the closing php tag `?>` would be processed first on the server before the output and every other thing not within the php tags are sent and rendered as HTML.

This means, the single line comment

```
//single line ignored
```

or block comment

```
/* Code here 
accross many lines would be ignored 
 */
```

are for PHP and should be used inside the PHP environment so that while it is interpreted on the server, whatever is commented would then be ignored by PHP and wouldn't be sent to HTML. 
Doing this

```
/*<?php include 'page1.php'?>*/
```

the PHP comments are outside the PHP environment which means they would not be interpreted as PHP but forward slash and asterisk (/*) and they don't mean anythind reasonable, what was within the php tags `<?php include 'page1.php'?>` still runs as PHP and the file is actually included. Hope you do understand.